# Нужно масштабировать блок в зависимости от размеров экрана и сохранять его содержимое внутри

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Задача следующая.

Имеется код.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы в зависимости от ширины экрана и его высоты блок всегда был в экране либо на 100% ширины, либо на 100% высоты. Более того, размеры блока всегда должны быть пропорциональны размерам фона. Как это сделать?

Вот сам код:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'San Francisco', Arial;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1920px;
  background: url('http://nubilonline.savgroup.ru/bg_1.png') no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.container>.header {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 3vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    header line
  </div>
  <div class="content">

  </div>
  <div class="footer">

  </div>
</div>
```

Вот графические примеры того, о чем я говорю

http://nubilonline.savgroup.ru/pic1.PNG
http://nubilonline.savgroup.ru/pic2.PNG

Comment: Как я понимаю это какие-то эелементы меню, в таком случае их нужно ровнять от того угла экрана где они находятся, и в принципе будет так как на картинке

Comment: Как изначально сделать так, чтобы сам блок имел ширину и высоту фона?

Comment: .container {     background-size: 100%;
    background-position: top; } + .header {    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; }

=) например

Answer (score 2):

Так, насколько я понял, то можно сделать так, фону задать background-size: 100% , а блоку задать например margin: auto; width: calc(100% -  40px); height: calc(100% - 20px); и готово , если есть блок с фоном и в нем другой блок, то он всегда будет уменьшаться вместе с изображением.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, но на JS

Вот пример http://nubilonline.savgroup.ru/page1.php

Можно ли тоже самое сделать на CSS ?